# Customer APP Demo Application Keycloak

Tags: java, maven, keycloak, demo

I have been trying to run the customer app that comes under the `\keycloak-master\examples\demo-template\customer-app` after reading the readme file.
My Keycloak is running from  executable and I am using `keycloak-4.1.0.Final.zip` package to run it in standard mode.

After running the keycloak I tried importing realm under `keycloak-master\examples\demo-template\testrealm.json` and all worked till now.

When I tried building the customerapp under `keycloak-master\examples\demo-template\customer-app > mvn clean install`

I get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - Secured via Valve 4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:jar:4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.230 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-27T14:31:08+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project customer-portal-example: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.keycloak.example.demo:customer-portal-example:war:4.2.0.Final-SNAP
SHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT, org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:jar:4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT: Could not fin
d artifact org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Can anyone help ? Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your webApp is not finding 4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar , you could verify this 4.2.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar in your maven repository.

The final version from maven repository is 4.1.0 Final

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-core/4.1.0.Final

You can try change to this version in pom.xml

I hope this help